# Why lhead overlaps chead?

Tags: header-footer, lyx

I couldn't find a solution on the internet nor this forum, if it already exist  - I'd be glad to receive the link to that place.

I opened a LaTeX ERT box inside lyx, and entered the following to create a header for my document:

```
\chead{hello}
\lhead{byebye}
```

And that's the result I get:
[image]

Why they're overlapping each other? How can I use both centered and left headers? It **doesn't** happen with `rhead`.

I also tried to use `fancyhead` with `L, C and R` and the results are the same.

I'm not using the default document class (I'm using Hebrew Article), but I also tried it on `Article (Standard Class)` and removed all the preambles - and it didn't helped.

There's also the point that the text is reflected which I solved with `\R\L`, like this:

```
 \rhead{\R{\L{Ariel}}}
```

## Setup:

- **Document class:** Hebrew Article
- **The installation instructions I've followed:** [here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~sameti/tex/lyxhebrew.html)
- **Latex configuration that might be relevant:**

  - bidi: CTAN: macros/latex/contrib/bidi/ (though I'm not using the package with `usepackage{bidi}`)
- **Tex Version:** 3.14159265 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
- **Used packages:** xy, amssymb, amsmath (in preamble)

Thanks!

Comment: Two questions: (a) Did you also run the instruction `\pagestyle{fancy}`? (b) How wide is the textblock?

Comment: Yep, I tried this: ```\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{Hello} 
\chead{byebye}```

Comment: And of course also tried with `fancyhead` instead of lhead/chead

Comment: In the screenshot you posted, the strings "byebye" and "hello" both appear to be running from right to left. Is this the case? If so, do please tell us (a lot!) more about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ, which TeX engine do you employ, and do you any special typesetting packages such as `bidi`? Please advise.

Comment: I just added more information, hope it's helpful and this is what you meant :) The strings are indeed reflected, which I solved with `\R\L` surrounding the text. I guess it's because the document is in Hebrew which is RTL - so by default all the text is RTL.

Comment: Just seen you edited the first comment:
If the text would be only in chead (or any of the other) it could fill the whole line without overlapping - it just seems the `lhead` behaves the same as `chead` no matter the length of the text

Comment: Can you provide more details?  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4488/15925 for how.